# What is the best way to store big amount of custom Python objects in a file?

Tags: python, file

I need some help to find the best way to store a big amount of data (1~2GB). The data source is a raw binary file containing network application packets exchanged between two device.

The packet class is defined in Python by myself (see below).

I would like to store my objects in such a way that I could later read the file packet by packet and not byte by byte

```py
class AppPacket:
    def __init__(self, version=0, command=0, flags=0, seq=0, pldlen=0, pld=[]):
        self.Version = np.uint8(version)
        self.Command = np.uint8(command)
        self.Flags = np.uint16(flags)
        self.SequenceNumber = np.uint16(seq)
        self.PayloadLength = np.uint16(pldlen)
        self.Payload = np.uint8(pld)
        self.CRC8 = np.uint8(0)
```

Reading byte by byte and parsing the data to rebuild each packet take at least 30minutes for 750MB. I expect to reduce this time as much as possible

Comment: Pickle module in python can be used for this https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html .

Comment: I'd rather use a Numpy archive for each packet, because you need to have the Python source to load pickled files which means you won't be able to load the files if you don't have the same source version anymore. (There are also security issues with Pickle). https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez

Comment: Does it have to be stored as Python objects? Have you considered something along the lines of [ProtocolBuffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). There are [python libraries](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) although it is language agnostic. For highly structured data like this it seems ideal.

Comment: @Kris , I could but it does not have good memory performance for big file. With less data, I would choose this solution

Comment: @AgostBiro , I didn't know this way thanks, unfortunately it would create thousands of files in the archive.

Comment: @Holloway , good point, I will try this option. To answer your question, the storage format is free as long as I can use it with Python

Comment: @Pascal If you think , its huge files and lot of data, definitely files is not the solution. You should think of a database which can scale!

Comment: @Kris, I agree with you: I am currently developping an interface to store my data in a SQLITE3 DB using the sqlite3 module of Python. So much easier to manipulate than file.

Thanks a lot to all of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this subject, as suggested by @Kris, the best way is to used a database. Since Python is offering native SQLite3 module, I choose to use it with SQLite Studio for DB management.

I use executemany() statement and multithreading to improve the performance during the storing process.

See : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm

Thanks to you :)